# How to replcae the occurance of a word coming after a particular word?

Tags: java, regex, replace

For example,
consider this as a `string`

```
a.prd_id IN     
(  SELECT prd_id FROM  prd)
```

I need to replace the text after `SELECT` i.e. `prd_id` to *period* and don't want to change the `prd_id` that is coming after `"a.prd_id"`

Sample output :

```
a.prd_id IN     
(  SELECT period FROM  prd)
```

Where ever the `prd_id` is coming after the `'Select'` keyword I have to replace it with `'period'`

Comment: Is that a multi-line string? What is your expected output?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah. Multistring and i have to replace the same in around 100 queries.

Comment: Tried regex ^,\\s,\\b but noting seems to be working ! noob in regex.

Comment: @laletscaria Update your question with that and add sample output, please/

Comment: Sample output : a.prd_id IN     
(  SELECT period FROM  prd)

Where ever the prd_id is coming after the 'Select' keyword I have to replace it with 'period'

Comment: @laletscaria you know, you can actually edit your question with all of that information?

Comment: @m.buettner Yeah buttner, Thank you for mentioning that. I am new to stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a positive look behind to achieve this.

```
(?i)(?<=SELECT\s)\s*prd_id\b
```

Comment: That's what i wanted :)  All hail stack overflow

Comment: Should use word boundaries otherwise it will also replace `prd_ids`

Comment: you mean \\b in the condition?

Comment: Also better to make it case insensitive to match `select` or `SELECT` using `(?i)` as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need positive lookbehind:

```
String s="a.prd_id IN\n" +     
    "( SELECT prd_id FROM prd)";
System.out.println("Replaced => " +
              s.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=\\bSELECT)(\\s+)prd_id\\b", "$1period"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Replaced => a.prd_id IN
( SELECT period FROM prd)
```

Comment: Why is that $needed there ?

Comment: To put 1 or more spaces between select and prd_id  back in replaced string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String inputString = "a.prd_id IN (SELECT prd_id FROM  prd)";
String constantSelect = "SELECT";
String constantFrom = "FROM";
String tmpString = "", resultString = "";
int startIndex =  inputString.indexOf(constantSelect);
int endIndex = inputString.indexOf(constantFrom);
tmpString = inputString.subString((startIndex + constantSelect.length), endIndex).trim;
resultString = inputString.replace(tmpString, "Your new string");
```

Comment: Will any kind of replace thing work , because I coded it in such a way. If I have to make it into separate string I need to change the entire code .

@Rock123 : thankyou for very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

a.substring(a.indexOf("(")+1,a.indexOf(")")).replace("prd_id", "?") where a is your string and '?' will be your replaced string

Comment: Let me try that thing :)